# Adding data to a specific column in a text file

Tags: vba, ms-access, text-files

I was wondering if there's a way in Access VBA to open a text file, and append data to the end of each line, at a specific column / space?

Basically, I need to open the text file and place a character at column # 300 of each line in the file (which is after all of the data).

I know I could just import the data into Access, add the column, and then export it, but for business reasons I'm trying to avoid this.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270732/vba-code-to-open-text-file will get you started on reading a text file. If you run into snags, post your code and we'll help you debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library.  Add a reference to that library in your VBA project.

Here is a procedure that will append a delimiter (I've used a comma in my sample) to the end of each record in the text file.

```
Private Const DELIMITER As String = "," 'this is the text file delimiter that will add a column
Private Const FILE_PATH As String = "C:\temp\" 'this is the directory where the text file resides

Private Sub AppendColumnToTextFile()

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim readStream As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim writeStream As Scripting.TextStream

    'this is the name of the text file that needs a column appended
    Dim currentFile As String: currentFile = "Test.csv"

    'this is a temp text file where we'll re-write each record with an additional column
    Dim tempFile As String: tempFile = "Test.New.csv"

    'set the read/write streams
    Set readStream = fso.OpenTextFile(FILE_PATH & currentFile, ForReading)
    Set writeStream = fso.OpenTextFile(FILE_PATH & tempFile, ForWriting, True)

    'read each line of the text file, and add a deilimeter at the end
    Do While Not readStream.AtEndOfStream
         writeStream.WriteLine readStream.ReadLine & DELIMITER
    Loop

   'close the streams
    readStream.Close
    writeStream.Close

    fso.CopyFile FILE_PATH & tempFile, FILE_PATH & currentFile, True  'copy the temp file to the original file path
    Kill FILE_PATH & tempFile 'delete the temp file

    Set writeStream = Nothing
    Set appendStream = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```